# Specifying a [Type] when adding a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need an Excel worksheet that has data in every row to run a macro that creates a sheet for every row and has each sheet be created with a custom template I have saved on my computer.

So far, I have the macro working to open each row in a sheet but I do not know how to get the sheet to open with the custom template. Also I'd like to rename every sheet corresponding to a specific cell in each sheet.

The current code I am using to create a new sheet from each row is:

```
Sub RowToSheet()
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim I As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        xRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For I = 1 To xRow
            Worksheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Row " & I
            .Rows(I).Copy Sheets("Row " & I).Range("A1")
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I am using to create the new sheet from each row

Comment: _to open each row in a sheet_ What does it mean? You mean _copy_ each row to sheet - not _open_?

Comment: If you have a template (*.xltx), then you can open it as a regular workbook with `Workbooks.Open`. The original template file is remained intact, of course.

Comment: I have a spreadsheet, each row is an individuals information, I take each row and create a new sheet in the same excel workbook each rows information is on the first line of each sheet created.

Comment: But your code is already doing it...

Comment: Code is good so far, but I don't understand what **get the sheet to open with the custom template** means. What does it mean to open a sheet with a template? Can you explain more about what you are trying to do here. Is there another workbook on your computer that has a worksheet in it that has some formatting you would like to apply to each newly created sheet?

Comment: Am I correct that you want to upload that row into template workbook?

Comment: I think there is an English language problem here: _sheets_ don't get opened, _workbooks_ get opened (including `xltx`). What's not clear to me is the end result should be one workbook with on sheet for every row, or one workbook for every row. @Ben can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: When I run the code I currently have, the sheet that is created only has one line of data, which is correct. What I want to change is the sheet that is created to open with a template I have saved, it's essentially a calendar, so that the user doesn't not need to copy and paste the calendar for each sheet.

Comment: Right... so again "Open with a template" is not clear. What does that mean? It's like saying to a mechanic "I want my car to totally jump the bacon when I gas the filter". Like... I'm certain YOU know what you want, but it needs some clarification for us to understand.

Comment: Basically I want the sheets that are created when I run the code I provided to open with a mon-fri calendar

Answer (score 2):

There is an annoying issue with the Excel object model here. You can't use Worksheets.Add and then use the Type parameter to specify the template. If you use Sheets.Add however, then it'll work.

Try this:

```
Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count), Type:=TemplatePath)
NewSheet.Name = "Row " & I.Rows(I)
NewSheet.Copy Sheets("Row " & I).Range("A1")
```

Set the TemplatePath variable to a suitable path.

Comment: This isn't an *annoying issue with VBA* at all. VBA isn't the Excel object model. Sorry for the pedantry, but things like this proves my point, that 95% of the hate VBA gets *as a language* is actually aimed at either the IDE or the type libraries people use. FWIW the `Worksheets` collection can only yield `Worksheet` objects, so it completely makes sense that it doesn't honor the `Type` parameter. Looks like the `Add` method/signature is inherited from the less specialized `Sheets` collection's interface, which handles a good half-dozen of legacy sheet types.

Comment: That said, +1 for shedding light on a rather obscure / rarely-used parameter. Would be nice to edit out the misguided annoyance though.